# requires named attributes

Tags: apache-flex, embed, assets

After I migrated my project from Windows to Mac, every time I try to embed an asset in Flash builder like this:

```
[Bindable] [Embed("assets/assets.swf#mySymbol")]
 public var myClass:Class;
```

I get this error:

```
[Embed] requires named attributes
```

if I close the files containing the embedding, it compiles fine and doesn't give any problem.
I googled the error, and haven't found anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly:

```
[Embed(source="assets/assets.swf", symbol="mySymbol")]
```

These are named attributes FB is telling you about - source and symbol.

Update: as Jason Towne mentioned, the only required attribute is source. Symbol allows to bind specific symbol from swf to variable.

Comment: As a side note, only the source attribute is required. symbol is optional.

Comment: tried it already, forgot to mention it in my question.. didn't make a difference :(

Comment: In such cases I'm creating project from scratch, might be some incorrect option in project settings...

Comment: actually, you were right in the first place, didn't notice the 'source' tag, don't know why :) thank you!